# Return value of environment variable with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the name of an environment variable in a variable and I want to get the value. How do I do that? I've tried:

```
PS C:\Users\Joe> $v="USERDOMAIN"
PS C:\Users\Joe> "$env:$v"
At line:1 char:2
+ "$env:$v"
+  ~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to
delimit the name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive

PS C:\Users\Joe> "$env:$($v)"
At line:1 char:2
+ "$env:$($v)"
+  ~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to
delimit the name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two lines

```
$v = "Path"
(get-item env:$v).Value
```

One line

```
iex ('$env:' + $x)
```

Comment: iex is a bad idea, e.g. if you have $x = '$(del -re -force c:\; "Path")' (say from an attacker) - then you'll be unhappy you used Invoke-Expression.

Comment: I agree with you. But plenty of scenarios allow to do it when no user input allowed

Comment: Thanks @JasonShirk do you have an alternative injection-proof solution?

Comment: The first example here is safe from injection.

Comment: @Vladmir - I know iex is safe for some scenarios, but people learn about it and misuse it so I try to steer people towards safer solutions and there usually are better/safer solutions.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Vladimir's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285082/45375) with a solution that makes direct use of the .NET framework:

```
$v="USERDOMAIN"
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($v)
```